# Alternative to using a list of Fragments?

Tags: java, android, list, templates, fragment

I want to have a list of pre-fabricated templates, where each item in the list has a first name, last name, and buttons that relate to that item in the list (Delete, rename, extra info, etc.) what would be the best way to do this?

The closest thing I can think of that would be similar would be something like a twitter feed: http://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Twitter-Feed.png

Where each "post" is based on a standard template, and database info is plugged into it, as well as buttons that belong to that post.

Currently I have it so my app uses a list of fragments, but that seems really hacked together and takes a lot of time to load more than a few of them.

Is there an alternative? I think I read somewhere of someone recommending another person to create a custom viewadapter, but as I am still somewhat new to android, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: One of the most common issues Android developers face is fragmentation, the variations in screen size and pixel density among the thousands of phones, tablets, and even desktop computers that run Android. The Fragments API helps you deal with this issue.

Comment: I'd like to see some examples of what you're talking about. From the way I read this, it's not "hacked together" but unnecessary.

Comment: updated the post with a better description of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a RecyclerView? It seems like you'll have a few specific layouts, which you can specify depending on what info you have in your list item, and you can handle expansion or more complex features by launching a new fragment afterwards

Comment: What's stopping me is I am very new to android and haven't heard of that before :/ will look into it :)